# bash regex expression '.*'

Tags: regex, bash, expression

I learned online that we can grep with `AND` statement by `.*`, i.e.:

```
aptitude search jdk | grep '7.*doc\|doc.*7'
```

_ _ _ _ p   openjdk-7-doc                   - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
, this works well.

but if we just use `*`, i.e.:

```
aptitude search jdk | grep '7*doc\|doc*7'
```

_ _ _ _ p   default-jdk-doc                 - Standard Java or Java compatible Developme
_ _ _ _ p   openjdk-6-doc                   - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentatio
_ _ _ _ p   openjdk-7-doc                   - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentatio
, this does not work well.

What is the meaning of the dot before the star(/Asterisk) ?

Comment: in regex dot means any character `.*` means any character repeated 0 or more times.

Comment: ^ To elaborate: `7*doc` would be 0+ 7's followed by doc (`doc`, `7doc`, `7777777doc`, but not `7-doc`).

Comment: This question is off topic on SO and should be directed to Unix/Linux or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**note:** regular expression syntax may vary among different programs...

in grep the `.` means "any character". `*` means; the previous character repeated 0, 1 or more times. So your expression

```
7.*
```

means: a `7` followed by "any character", repeated any number of times (0, 1 or more), ie: a `7` followed by any succession of characters. The other expression

```
7*
```

means: the character `7`, repeated 0, 1 or more times; thus matching any document; only the rest of your regular expression is still working...